# Is this question on topic here?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I have a question about cryptography algorithm difference:

Rhinjael has been choosen over Serpent (and other) for AES. However, Serpent has been considere less vulnerable to attack in theory. But, attacks on Serpent are less studied and implementation are less controled.
My question is: Is it safer to run Serpent or AES? (Trade a safer encryption for a safer implementation)

I don't know if this question should be in cryptography or here.

And maybe it can be considere opinion based?

Comment: this belongs at crypto

Comment: @shroeder Ok, I asked because the question is also about implementation security and I don't think it belong to crypto.

And will this question considered opinion-based?

Comment: That's going to be up to them